# Select rows with same ID but different values

Tags: mysql

I would like to have a list from the table USERS that gives me all USERS that have the same COMPANYID but where the address 1 or address 2 not match.

```
| USER  |COMPANYID| ADDRESS 1     | ADDRESS 2
|     1 | A       | Street A     | 11
|     2 | A       | Street A     | 11
|     3 | B       | Street B     | 12
|     4 | B       | Street B     | 13
|     5 | C       | Street C     | 14
|     6 | C       | Street C     | 14
|     7 | C       | Street C     | 15
|     8 | D       | Street C     | 15
```

I would like to get all the rows where the COMPANYID exists more than one time but the address between the users in the company is not matching. This is what I would like to get:

```
| userID| COMPANYID| ADDRESS 1    | ADDRESS 2
|     3 | B        | Street B     | 12
|     4 | B        | Street B     | 13
|     5 | C        | Street C     | 14
|     6 | C        | Street C     | 14
|     7 | C        | Street C     | 15
```

I can get the first part with the query:

```
SELECT *FROM USERS WHERE comapnyID IN (SELECT companyID FROM USERS GROUP BY companyID HAVING COUNT(*)>1) ORDER BY companyID
```

But I don't want to include those where the address already matches.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult :)

```
select * from USERS where companyid in (
    select t1.companyid  from (
        SELECT n.companyid,n.address1,n.address2,
            CASE WHEN n.address1=o.address1 AND n.address2=o.address2 THEN "No Change"
            ELSE "Changed"
            END as ChangeFlag
        FROM USERS n
        LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS o ON n.companyid=o.companyid
        ) t1
    where ChangeFlag="Changed")
 order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below query

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE comapnyID IN (SELECT COUNT(companyID) FROM USERS GROUP BY companyID HAVING COUNT(companyID)>1) group by comapnyID ORDER BY companyID
```

Comment: This one does not include the address.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It does not take it account if the address is similar or not. But thanks for your help! It's appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT 
    A.*
FROM
    USERS AS A
        JOIN
    USERS AS B ON A.COMPANYID = B.COMPANYID
       and A.userId = B.userId
        AND A.ADDRESS2 <> B.ADDRESS2
        AND A.ADDRESS1 <> B.ADDRESS1
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but not if there are 3 users with the similar companyID.

Comment: Add user_id clause in on

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.* FROM
USERS T
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT T1.COMPANYID FROM
  (
    SELECT COMPANYID,COUNT(*) AS CADDRESS2 
    FROM USERS 
    WHERE COMPANYID IN (SELECT COMPANYID FROM USERS GROUP BY COMPANYID HAVING COUNT(*)>1) 
    GROUP BY COMPANYID
  ) AS T1
    INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT COMPANYID,COUNT(*) CADDRESS2 
    FROM USERS 
    WHERE COMPANYID IN (SELECT COMPANYID FROM USERS GROUP BY COMPANYID HAVING COUNT(*)>1) 
    GROUP BY COMPANYID,ADDRESS2
  ) AS T2
  ON T1.COMPANYID = T2.COMPANYID
  AND T1.CADDRESS2 != T2.CADDRESS2
) AS T4
ON T.COMPANYID = T4.COMPANYID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
USER    COMPANYID   ADDRESS1    ADDRESS2
3       B           Street B    12
4       B           Street B    13
5       C           Street C    14
6       C           Street C    14
7       C           Street C    15
```

**LIVE DEMO**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a153b/35

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the work you put into this. This seems to work! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome If You got your answer please accept and upvote @Sport50

Comment: I was checking again, it works for this one, but not if address 1 is different.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY COMPANYID,CONCAT(ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2)` IN place of `GROUP BY COMPANYID,ADDRESS2` AND then check @Sport50

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

SELECT * FROM `USERS` 
WHERE `COMPANYID` IN (SELECT `COMPANYID` FROM `USERS` WHERE `userID`!=0 GROUP BY `COMPANYID` HAVING COUNT(*)>1) 
AND `COMPANYID` NOT IN (
SELECT `COMPANYID` FROM `USERS` GROUP BY `COMPANYID`,`address1`,`address2` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) ORDER BY `COMPANYID`